# Sorting by median in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to graph a discrete integer number `a` by another discrete number `b`. I want to show the median and IQR of `b` for each `a` with the X-axis sorted by the median of `b`. I have used the following code:

```
a<-sample(1:10, 1000, replace=TRUE)
b <- sample(1:300, 1000, replace=TRUE)
df<-data.frame(a,b)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x = reorder(a, b, median),
                    y = b)) +
    labs(x="a", y="b", title="Variation of b by a") + 
    stat_summary(fun.y    = function(z) { median(z) },
                 fun.ymin = function(z) { quantile(z, 0.25) },
                 fun.ymax = function(z) { quantile(z, 0.75) }) + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
    theme_classic()
```

And end up with the following result:

[image]

This is what I'm looking for except that the last point is not in line with the other points. Why is the last point not sorted properly?

Comment: can you please add a reproducible example?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: When I run the code (and data) you shared in a new R session, it works just fine. Can't reproduce the problem...

Comment: Hi, I cant share the specific data, but I added the creation of a data frame that should be able to recreate what I have. I am more interested to know if anyone knows why I am getting a result that isn't "completely" sorted.

Comment: Yea, I dont actually know how to recreate the problem I am having without the data I have, and unfortunately I cannot share that.

Comment: Not much we can do if we can't see the problem. I would suggest that perhaps you could anonymize your data (or anonymize a subset of it that shows the problem). I haven't used it, but you could try out the [`anonymizer` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=anonymizer). Find the smallest possible subset that illustrates the problem and see if you can find the problem or alter it enough to share. Like, if you try your code on `df2 = subset(your_data, a %in% c("20", "16", "15"))` do you still get the problem? Etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622979/reorder-not-correctly-reordering-a-factor-variable-in-ggplot suggests that clearing the workspace and restarting R may work.